# Business English Semantic Shift of "Abreast"

Tags: business-language, semantic-shift

My coworker just sent out an email asking someone to *[please] keep **abreast** for a response*. My understanding is that the phrase is *keep abreast **of x***, and that it is used to mean actively keeping up with **x**, which is supported by the [idiomatic definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/keep+abreast+of). (**Edit for clarification:** The intended meaning in the email is *"wait for a response"*.)

I am aware of the phenomenon of words taking on different meanings in business contexts, but this is not one that I have come across before (in my admittedly short time in the corporate world). Is this commonly used elsewhere?

Comment: It's common enough. It's unusual to use it without the "of...", but it's easily understandable here that it's short for "keep abreast of the situation" or similar.

Comment: But wouldn't *keep abreast of a situation* be the opposite action of *wait for a response*?

Comment: Exactly. It isn't asking them to "wait" for a response it's asking them to actively look out for one.

Comment: There does seem to be a pattern in Business English of 1. Take idiomatic phrase. 2. Remove prepositions, and possibly object. 3. Expect people to understand what you mean.

Comment: Someone might say 'You can intransitivise any preposition'. But here the preposition is/was 'abreast of'.

Comment: There's **no** semantic shift. Verb: **keep abreast** Keep informed "He kept abreast on his country's foreign policies" http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/KEEPABREAST

Comment: We need to see usage examples also.

Comment: @Kris the fact that this usage has already been recorded doesn't necessarily mean it isn't the product of a shift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use the term keep abreast FOR a response - you keep abreast OF something, not FOR something. The former does not really constitute normal use of the term.

Comment: The distribution of the adverb _abreast_ is far from simple. RHK has: **abreast adv: 2. informed; aware; up-to-date** but thenn gives the example using what I'd call a MWV or perhaps a compound preposition usage:  _to keep abreast of new developments_. Collins stipulates necessary complements for the adjective usage: abreast 2. (foll by: of or with) up to date (with); fully conversant (with)

Comment: Its use in most of the recent contexts is metaphorical.

Answer (score 1):

Both 'for' and 'of' are correct but the latter is presently favored:

Historical usage in a (legally produced) governmental contract:

> In order to meet these requirements, up-to-date equipment is a prime
>   factor. New construction equipment is required in order **to keep
>   abreast for** the new methods and techniques of construction work. ****-Hearings Cong. 84 sess. 1 Appropriations v. 2 1955.****

&

A book on a family's colonial history:

> These things must come whenever people or nations advance in education
>   and science, besides mechanical arts. Constitutional governments must
>   advance **and keep abreast for** the protection of the people.-Beighley, 1737-1934; acorns from colonial oaks

Comment: In the second example you give, 'for' is not linked to 'abreast' in the same sense as the first example.